# On setting any property of class A, set property of abstract class B (which is inherited from class A)

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
public abstract class ANetworkedComponent
{
    public bool Dirty { get; set; } = false;
}
```

```
public class Collider: ANetworkedComponent
{
    public Vector2 Velocity { get; set; }
}
```

I need to set `Dirty` to `true` every time a property of a class that inherits from `ANetworkedComponent` is modified. For example, when

```
var collider = new Collider();
collider.Velocity = new Vector(10, 10);
```

is executed, then collider.Dirty should be set to `true`.

Modifying the properties manually is not an option because there are too many properties and it's not `DRY`. Are there other options?

Comment: It looks like a DRY violation only because you have one `Dirty` Property for the class. If you had `PropertyDirty` for each property, you wouldn't say that was a DRY violation. That said, the complaint about writing all that code is real. Look into "Aspect Oriented Programming". There are libraries for C#, like PostSharp, that allow you to add aspects to classes. For example, you could have PostSharp auto-implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your classes for you, which you could use to set this `Dirty` Property. https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged.

Comment: It works well. With AOP you typically basically decorate your properties with an attribute and then the behavior you want is injected during compilation.

Comment: Looks like what I need. Can't believe I didn't know about this before.

Comment: okay, I'll add my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only looks like a DRY violation because you only have one `Dirty` Property for the whole class. If you had a separate `IsPropertyDirty` for each property, you wouldn't say that was a DRY violation.

The fastest (execution time-wise), is going to be properties you write yourself. But as you have noted, it is the most developer time consuming, so I would only do that if performance profiling indicates it.

Another quick option would be "Aspect Oriented Programming". There are libraries for C#, like PostSharp, that allow you to add 'aspects' to classes. For example, you could have [PostSharp auto-implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged.) on your classes for you, which you could then use to listen for property changes and set `Dirty`. I'm sure you can also add your own aspect to change the Dirty state under various conditions.

PostSharp is in a class of AOP libraries that weaves code into your assemblies during compilation. Typically you decorate classes, properties, and methods with attributes and that tells PostSharp what behaviors to implement automatically in your code. There are also libraries that support runtime aspects (many IOC containers support this), and although performance won't match those of a code generated AOP, they are quite serviceable.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic property with a virtual field inside that uses reflection to change the Dirty flag on the set of that inner property

Comment: This would be a great solution if the properties would not be modified so fast. In my case. the properties are modified so fast that reflection would cause severe performance problems.

Comment: Cache the PropertyInfo for the properties as they are used so they only get looked up once per Type, and that lessens the performance hit significantly.